# struct and :: - what does it do

Tags: c++, struct

Can someone tell me where this structure language is from? I am not familiar with it in my knowledge of C or java and Google isn't a big help here.

Mainly, I've never seen the use of "::" in a struct. What is it's name and what does it do?

An example that I'm seeing is:

```
struct msg
{ 
  common::messageHeader sHeader;
  common::flag sFlag;
};
```

Thank you for your guidance!

Comment: Is that actually from C++?  If so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator

Comment: I don't believe that operator exists in C

Comment: "*Google isn't a big help here*" You must not have tried very hard -- searching for "C++ operators" is guaranteed to turn it up.

Comment: "Mainly, I've never seen the use of "::" in a struct" ... `::` can appear anywhere, just not in C. :P

Comment: Didn't know it was C++..

Comment: Ah, apologies, I didn't realize you weren't the one who tagged the question `c++`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`::` is not a C operator, but the scope resolution operator in C++.

It can be used (in C++) to qualify members belonging to a `class`, `struct` or a `namespace`.

**If** this was C++, its use would be something like:

```
namespace common
{
  struct messageHeader {};
  enum flag
  {
     flag1,
     flag2
  };
}

struct msg
{ 
  common::messageHeader sHeader;
  common::flag sFlag;
};
```